# XSLT transformation from XML to XML document

Tags: xml, spring, xslt

I need help to get correct XSL transformation, I am expecting the source XML to be copied as is and do the required updates to the target XML file. Right now i am trying 2 things, first is to copy source to target XML and second is to update the namespace URL and version attribute of root element. Please find the code below and let me know what is going wrong because i am getting only root element in the target xml, the content is missing, the end tag for root element is missing and also the attribute version was not updated.

Source XML-

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:v1="http://www.abc.com/s/v1.0">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<v1:QueryRequest version="1">
<subject>
<dataList>
<!--1 or more repetitions:-->
<dataset>
<type>company</type>
<value>abc</value>
</dataset>
<dataset>
<type>user</type>
<value>xyz</value>
</dataset>
</dataList>
</subject>
<!--Optional:-->
<testList>
<!--1 or more repetitions:-->
<criteria>
<type>test</type>
<value>972</value>
</criteria>
<criteria>
<type>test2</type>
<value>false</value>
</criteria>
</testList>
</v1:QueryRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

XSL file :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:old="http://www.abc.com/s/v1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="old">    
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"  version="1.0" />

<xsl:param name="newversion" select="2.0"> </xsl:param>
<!-- replace namespace of elements in old namespace -->

<xsl:template match="old:*">
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.abc.com/s/v2.0">
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='QueryRequest']/@version">
<xsl:attribute name="version">
<xsl:value-of select="$newversion"/>
</xsl:attribute>

</xsl:template>
```

Output using above XSL file:-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body><ns7:QueryRequest version="1" xmlns=""
xmlns:ns6="http://www.abc.com/s/v1.0" 
xmlns:ns7="http://www.abc.com/s/v2.0"/>

</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

"

Expected Output:

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:v2="http://www.abc.com/s/v2.0">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<v2:QueryRequest version="2.0">
<subject>
<dataList>
<!--1 or more repetitions:-->
<dataset>
<type>company</type>
<value>abc</value>
</dataset>
<dataset>
<type>user</type>
<value>xyz</value>
</dataset>
</dataList>
</subject>
<!--Optional:-->
<testList>
<!--1 or more repetitions:-->
<criteria>
<type>test</type>
<value>972</value>
</criteria>
<criteria>
<type>test2</type>
<value>false</value>
</criteria>
</testList>
</v2:QueryRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Spring config Code which triggers this transformation -

```
<int-xml:xslt-transformer  id="v2transformer"                                     xsl-resource="classpath:transformtoversion2.xslt" 
input-channel="AChannel" output-channel="BChannel" 
result-transformer="resultTransformer"> 
</int-xml:xslt-transformer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, once I correct the XSLT by renaming the root element to `xsl:stylesheet` instead of `xsl:transform`, I get almost the correct output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://www.abc.com/s/v1.0">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<QueryRequest xmlns="http://www.abc.com/s/v2.0" version="2">
<subject xmlns="">
<dataList>
<!--1 or more repetitions:-->
<dataset>
<type>company</type>
<value>abc</value>
</dataset>
<dataset>
<type>user</type>
<value>xyz</value>
</dataset>
</dataList>
</subject>
<!--Optional:-->
<testList xmlns="">
<!--1 or more repetitions:-->
<criteria>
<type>test</type>
<value>972</value>
</criteria>
<criteria>
<type>test2</type>
<value>false</value>
</criteria>
</testList>
</QueryRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

the only semantically significant difference from what you require being `version="2"` rather than `version="2.0"`, which can be fixed by adding some quotes to

```
<xsl:param name="newversion" select="'2.0'" />
```

to set the param value to the *string* 2.0 instead of the *number* 2.

---

For the cosmetic differences, if you want to remove the unused `xmlns:v1` from the root element and use a prefix for the `QueryRequest` element instead of a default namespace (which is then countermanded by `xmlns=""` for the children) then you need something more like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:old="http://www.abc.com/s/v1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="old"
xmlns:v2="http://www.abc.com/s/v2.0">    
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"  version="1.0" />

  <xsl:param name="newversion" select="'2.0'"/>

  <!-- fix namespace declarations on root element -->
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
      <!-- copy the v2: binding from the stylesheet document -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/namespace::v2" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- replace namespace of elements in old namespace -->
  <xsl:template match="old:*">
    <xsl:element name="v2:{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="old:QueryRequest/@version">
    <xsl:attribute name="version">
      <xsl:value-of select="$newversion"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I use `<xsl:element>` instead of `<xsl:copy>` in the `/*` template because `copy` copies the namespace bindings from the original tag.

---

From the comments, you now want to upper-case all the `<type>` values.  You can achieve this simply by adding one extra template

```
<xsl:template match="type/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(., 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                                     'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')" />
</xsl:template>
```

There isn't a simple `to-upper-case` function as such in XPath 1.0, but you can use `translate(X, Y, Z)`, which goes through the string X replacing each character in Y with the character at the same position in Z.

This will convert *all* `type` elements, if you only want to convert the dataset types and not the criteria types then just use a more specific `match="dataset/type/text()"`.

Comment: Thanks for the great perfect soultion, on my end this is not yet complete because when i use your XSL i get what i expected expect the <type> element and the reason being when i transform the source XML to target XML which then goes to unmarshalling and then marshalling using version 2 schema and now in version 2 of the schema all the types are in captials :-) so that is the reason why all the <type> elements are missing from the output....Can you suggest how can update the <type> elements values to CAPS in simple way please?

Comment: For example i need to type elements to be like             <type>COMPANY</type> or <type>SERVICE</type> and so on....

Comment: excellent...i will try this ..Thanks for a lot, appreciate it.